# laravel eager load first of one to many ordered relation

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a model Item, an Item can have multiple pictures.

```
public function pictures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Picture')->orderBy('priority', 'asc');
}
```

The pictures have a property `priority`. For each item most times I want to show the highest pirority picture, so I made:

```
public function getMainpictureAttribute()
{
    //I will later add some check to show a default picture if no picture is set.
    return $this->pictures()->orderBy('priority', 'asc')->first()->getPath();
}
```

When I load my items with `Item::with('pictures')->get();`

And in my view show I loop over the items and call `$picture->mainpicture()`, I can see that there is a query for each item where I call mainpicture.
Is it possible to eager load this?
I have pages with +-200 items and would prefer one query instead of 200.

Comment: In which model is the getMainpictureAttribute() function ? it seems like in Item model, but then in the post you've mentioned $picture->mainpicture() . Please clarify

Comment: so you want to define a second relationship as a `hasOne` relationship and order it by `priority` `asc` ... then you can eager load that ... but regardless of what you do in that accessor you can not directly call the relationship method or it will cause a new query, you need to be accessing the dynamic property

Comment: @Aashishgaba that is how laravel mutators are defined. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Okay, my bad. I posted the answer thinking that you just wanted the one with the min value.

Comment: And what if you have this in your mutator? `$this->pictures->sortBy('priority')->first()` , this is a collection method and won't make a query to the database. And the pictures relation would have been already eager loaded. Let me know if i got this wrong :)

Comment: @Aashishgaba Nice that seems to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you would have already eager loaded the pictures relation, you could use collection method sortBy and then get the first instance(therefore no DB query)

Inside the mutator

```
$this->pictures->sortBy('priority')->first();
```

Comment: By using a mutator I only have to change it in one place, lets say I want to change the mainPicture to something else, with a mutator I only have to update one function. With your method I have to find every spot where I want to show a main picture.